# How to specify the so path when using Valgrind

Tags: valgrind

When I am using Valgrind to analyse a Rust app in macOS 13.4.1 (c)  with Intel chip like this, I get an error:

```
~/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server/target/debug on  main! ⌚ 19:34:50
$ valgrind ./texhub-server                                                                                                                 ‹ruby-2.7.2›
==44422== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==44422== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==44422== Using Valgrind-3.22.0.GIT-lbmacos and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==44422== Command: ./texhub-server
==44422==
--44422-- run: /usr/bin/dsymutil "./texhub-server"
dyld[44422]: Library not loaded: libsynctex_parser.so
  Referenced from: <7EF21E86-72BE-30C2-B78A-4E8187973103> /Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server/target/debug
  Reason: tried: 'libsynctex_parser.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OSlibsynctex_parser.so' (no such file), 'libsynctex_parser.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libsynctex_parser.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libsynctex_parser.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server/target/debug/libsynctex_parser.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server/target/debug/libsynctex_parser.so' (no such file), '/Users/dolphin/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server/target/debug/libsynctex_parser.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libsynctex_parser.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libsynctex_parser.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
[1]    44422 killed     valgrind ./texhub-server
(base)
```

The so lib path is `~/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server/src/so`, is it possible to specify the so path when running Valgrind command? This is the Valgrind version:

```
$ valgrind --version                                                                                                                       ‹ruby-2.7.2›
valgrind-3.22.0.GIT-lbmacos
(base)
```

Comment: Does macOS use rpath?

Comment: I am not using the rpath, I specify the rust link c dynamic so file from .cargo/config.coml file. like this: `rustflags = ["-L", "./src/so"]`

Comment: Your exe needs to find the library some way. I'm not very familiar with macOS for development. I think it uses rpath and otherwise can use DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.